# opengl difference setting value in layout location or uniform variable

Tags: c++, shader, opengl-4

i am trying to get myself familiar with opengl programming. I cant stop wondering when should i use layout for variable input to a shader (with glVertexAttribPointer) vs just setting an uniform  with glUniform. What are the advantage and when should i use one over the other? 
kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with the value. If you want to pass in a *single* value to the shader, which won't change for each vertex, then you use a uniform. If you want to pass in multiple values so each vertex can have a different value, then you use an attribute pointer.